# How to store navigator.geolocation in string variable?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, navigator

**Hi, I do not understand why storing the *navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition* result in a variable and use it to concatenate with other string doesn't work**

**If I just type in any city name for the ${locationName} in the *forWeather variable* then it works fine but of course the point of this is that I want to use user's location. Please help**

```
const successfulLookup = position =>{
    const { lat, long } = position
    const forFetch = `https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json?q=${lat}+${long}&key=87c637778f19465f89895cad4bf83cfa`
    fetch(forFetch)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(res => res.results[0].components.village)
    .then(console.log)
}

const locationName = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successfulLookup)

const forWeather = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${locationName}&appid=cb79b904798a1f67e15e9d71fb81bc11`


$.getJSON(forWeather, 
    function(data){
         console.log(data)
```

Comment: [Read the API's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition): (1) it does not return a location name, and (2) it requires you to supply a success callback since it is an asynchronous operation. Do read up more about handling async operations: what you basically want is to actually wait for the lookup and then perform the `$.getJSON()` request in the success callback.

Answer (score 0):

Both `getCurrentPosition()` and `fetch()` are asynchronous.

Your flow needs to look more like:

```
const successfulLookup = position => {
   getLocationName(position).then(getWeatherData)
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successfulLookup)

const getLocationName = position => {
  const {lat, long } = position
  const forFetch = `https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json?q=${lat}+${long}&key=87c637778f19465f89895cad4bf83cfa`

  // return the fetch promise
  return fetch(forFetch)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(res => res.results[0].components.village)
  //.then(console.log) must reurn data after this log !!
}

const getWeatherData = locationName => {
  const forWeather = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${locationName}&appid=cb79b904798a1f67e15e9d71fb81bc11`

  return fetch(forWeather)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data=>{
        // consume the wather data
        console.log(data)
     })

}
```

Comment: **Hi it keeps telling me:** " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined at successfulLookup (weather.js:2) " 

const successfulLookup = position => { getLocationName(position).then(getWeatherData) }

Comment: Oops ... I left a comment to *"return the fetch promise"* in `getLocationName()` and left out the `return` statement. See update

Comment: Hi I wanted to use the URL that you've helped me earlier but then I've use it in the function below, it throws an error... pls can you help again

Comment: Actually!!! I've done it!! I've done it!!! OMG OMG OMG!!! THANK YOU SOOO MUCH!!! THANK YOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU!!! I've been stuck on this for 2 days straight and you've saved lots on my remaining hair!!!! You're so kind!!!!!

Comment: Great. Feels satisfying when you jump a hurdle like that

Comment: YES! And BTW, this is my first time on StackOverFlow. I've literally just signed up and this is my first question!! Thank you for making me feel so welcome. First impression count!!❤️ 

Comment: The web is full of *"SO is toxic"*. It's actually a huge helpful community where thousands of questions a week get help...and quickly

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON(getWeatherData, function(data){
    console.log(data)

    let weatherDescription = data.weather[0].description
    let temp = data.main.temp
    let location = data.name

    const kelvin = temp
    const celsius = kelvin - 273
    let newton = celsius * ( 33 / 100 )
    newton = Math.floor(newton)

    $(".iconDescription").append(weatherDescription)
    $(".temperature").append(newton + " ˚C")
    $(".location").append(location)

    switch (weatherDescription){
        case "clear sky":
            $(".Clouds").css("display", "none")
            $(".overcastClouds").css("display", "none")
            $(".moderateRain").css("display", "none")
        break;
        case "Clouds":
            $(".clearskyIcon").css("display", "none")
            $(".overcastClouds").css("display", "none")
            $(".moderateRain").css("display", "none")
        break;
        case "broken clouds":
            $(".clearskyIcon").css("display", "none")
            $(".Clouds").css("display", "none")
            $(".overcastClouds").css("display", "none")
            $(".moderateRain").css("display", "none")
        break;
        case "overcast clouds":
            $(".clearskyIcon").css("display", "none")
            $(".Clouds").css("display", "none")
            $(".moderateRain").css("display", "none")
        break;
        case "moderate rain":
            $(".clearskyIcon").css("display", "none")
            $(".Clouds").css("display", "none")
            $(".overcastClouds").css("display", "none")
        break;
        case "few clouds":
            $(".clearskyIcon").css("display", "none")
            $(".overcastClouds").css("display", "none")
            $(".moderateRain").css("display", "none")
        break;
        default:
            $(".clearskyIcon").css("display", "none")
            $(".Clouds").css("display", "none")
            $(".overcastClouds").css("display", "none")
            $(".moderateRain").css("display", "none")
    }
})
```